# How can I get back to directory line from the MySQL line?

Tags: debian, directory, mysql

I’m not sure exactly what I did, but I entered into MySQL and now I cannot return to the directory line.

How can I leave

```
mysql> cd ..
```

and return to

```
 debian@beaglebone:/home$ cd ..
```

Answer (score 4):

This `mysql>` is not a directory.
It is the mysql database prompt, where you can execute mysql commands.
You can exit this CLI by typing "quit".

Comment: Yeah I know is not directory exactly but thanks for the help